# How to represent table with nulls in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

What should I do to represent this table in Spring Data Java Persistence Application Programming Interface (JPA)?

The table is specific because it has **no primary key** and **every column in the table can have nulls**, and it is **read only**.

In entity class I can not simply annotate a single column with `@id` because there is no column with unique values.
I can, of course, create composite virtual primary key in entity class by annotating every column with `@id`, and that works, but only if there are no `null`s in the row. So if I select row(s) with all columns not `null` then this works. But if one or more columns contains `null`, Spring is not able to extract that row from table, and instead returns simply `null` for entire row rather than returning an entity object with only the appropriate field `null`.

Please do not say "just add id column to the table" because table is read only for us. My company was negotiating for more then a month just to get the read rights to the table! I can not simply add `id` field in the table.

What else can I do in this case? Other than manually executing a query and extracting the result. Can I somehow fake the `id` field to make Spring happy? `id` field is not important for our application, we will never filter the table by `id`, so it can be whatever makes Spring happy as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do that.

Just get a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` injected and query away.

A central premise of JPA is that you can load data from a bunch of tables, edit the resulting object structure and JPA will take note and mirror the changes to the data in the database.
If you don't have anything to use as an id you wouldn't know which row to update. So this whole approach kinda fails to work.

Comment: Why would an `@Embeddable` that is `@Transient` not work?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Not sure what you would do with that.

Comment: I guess I was thinking that using and `@Embeddable` class that constructs UUID that is either static or `@Transient` could be used to satisfy JPA's ID requirement. (`@EmbeddedId`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@EmeddedId` with an ID you create. Set the ID field either `@Transient` or `static` so it won't affect persistence.

In the below example I use the UUID static method `.randomUUID()` to generate the ID.

So put this into your `@Entity` and you will get every row regardless of `null`s. Inserts will work just fine too (depending on how you disambiguate your rows).

```java
    @EmbeddedId
    static UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Comment: I can not get your solution to work. If I only put your code in my entity class I get ```No identifier specified for entity``` error. If I then annotate other fields with ```@Id``` I still get ```null``` instead of entity object when the column which I annotated with ```@Id``` contains ```null```.
Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: When I tested this I was using JDBCTemplate and BeanPropertyRowMapper and it worked like a charm. It sounds like your table may be more complex than a simple set of nullable columns. Is your entity class something you can post up?

Comment: @KRISTIJANTOMASINI - I wasn't using hibernate. That is a Hibernate error. What happens if you include `@Id` along with `@EmbeddedId`?